Custom Labelling in Multi-Class Classification in XGBoost/ LightGBM
I have the following dataframe which records the IQ, Hours (number of hours of studying) and Score (past exam score for student 1,2,3,4 in different classes (Class_ID) and I would like to use these features to predict who is going to graduate top of their class (Top)
Class_ID IQ_1 IQ_2 IQ_3 IQ_4 Hours_1 Hours_2 Hours_3 Hours_4 Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4 Top
1        101  99   130  100  10      19      3       12      98      80      95      88      3     
2        93   103  112  200  5       9       12      10      50      88      99      100     1
3        100  102  101  102  12      13      17      9       84      88      89      98      4

To do that, I use the multi-class classification in XGBoost library (with the classes being 1,2,3,4). However, since the person ended up second in class is close to the top but in the training he/she will get a 0 anyway, a better training scheme would be to reward the top person with highest score, and the second person some score instead of giving it 0 like the person at the bottom. Hence I would like to ask in XGBoost, is there anyway to do custom labelling like:
Class_ID IQ_1 IQ_2 IQ_3 IQ_4 Hours_1 Hours_2 Hours_3 Hours_4 Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Score_4 Student_1 Student_2 Student_3 Student_4
1        101  99   130  100  10      19      3       12      98      80      95      88      0         0.3       0.7       0
2        93   103  112  200  5       9       12      10      50      88      99      100     0.7       0         0.3       0
3        100  102  101  102  12      13      17      9       84      88      89      98      0         0.3       0       0.7

i.e. where we reward the the top of the class 0.7 and the second in the class 0.3 ([0, 0.3, 0.7, 0] for Class 1 as opposed to [0,0,1,0] in the original label?)
Thank you so much in advance.
Edit: If XGBoost doesn't have this kind of custom labelling, can we do that in similar packages like LightGBM/ Catboost?

XGBoost  deosnt allows you to customize the labels in multi-class classification tasks
directly with fractional labels for rankings. What you can do is you can modify your dataset to represent these fractional labels and use them as target values for training.
